# FCM - Only 'display' push notification when app is in background

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, I have push notifications being sent and received in my Xamarin app. When I send a push notification the sneak peak dialogue is displayed when the app is in the foreground & also the background. I am trying to only visual display a push notification when the app is in the background. When the user is in the foreground the notification just sneaks into the HUD and is not displayed.

Here is my code:

### Xamarin Android

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FCMMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            var _message = message.GetNotification().Body;
            var _title = message.GetNotification().Title;
            MainActivity.SendNotification(_title, _message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Was NotificationType null? this should never be null anyways
        }
    }
}
```

### API - Android Payload

```
    return new JObject(
           new JObject(
                   new JProperty("notification",
                       new JObject(
                           new JProperty("body", message),
                           new JProperty("title", title),
                           new JProperty("icon","toasticon"), 
                           new JProperty("user", fromId != null ? fromId.ToString() : "")
                        )
                    ),
                   new JProperty("data",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("notificationtype", notificationType)
                            )
                   )
                )
       ).ToString();
```

Comment: From your payload send only `data` key not `notification`.

Comment: @Arvindraja You win the chicken dinner! This was the answer I was looking for. If you could kinda repost your comment as the answer I can award you the win. As an added bonus would you be able to explain the best approach to how I should detect whether the user is in foreground or background and based upon that Show/Hide notification? I can do this with SignalR but I am wondering if FCM already has some capability.

Comment: @XamDev89- You could ask separate question for your other clarification that would be more good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the [firebase setup for xamarin android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin)

You might have read there that foreground notifications have to be displayed manually,

**How to do that?**

***This is how***

In the setup, you will have a class inheriting from `FirebaseMessagingService`

In that class, there will be a piece of code something like this():

```
 var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
                                              MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                              intent,
                                              PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

var notificationBuilder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                          .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                          .SetContentText(messageBody)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true)
                          .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

 var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
 notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, 
 notificationBuilder.Build());
```

This piece of code sends the notification to the Android tray, When in the foreground and hence if you comment this you will get the desired output.

Good luck!

In case of queries revert.

Comment: Wow, nailed it. Thank you @g.hakim

Comment: Sure no problem, Mark the answer as correct please so other people out for the same question know!